# How to directly wire a solar panel through the wall socket without a battery?

Tags: power-supply, inverter, wiring, amperage, solar-energy

I apologize for this the multi-ponged line of questions. I am thinking, I can wire the solar panel to a pure sine wave inverter then use a extension cord with 2 male plugs, one going to the inverter and the other going to the socket? If the socket is rated for 30 amps then I should input less than that in amps from the inverter not to overload the socket? Also, any appliances on that circuit should not exceed the output amp capacity of the inverter?
There may be some issues like having stable amperage. I'm thinking, in order to make this work safely using wall plugs and not directly hooking up to fuse box, I should designate a circuit just for the solar panels?
[image]

Comment: Your solar regulator will probably not start or at least not run properly without a battery. Also, obvious elephant in the room is that the inverter will shut down immediately for any shade.

Comment: @winny yes I would need devices with internal memory and/or small battery just for the memory. Also the the solar charger would maintain a charging voltage in shade.

Comment: `extension cord with 2 male plugs` ... suicide cord

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea (especially the suicide cord). Why not buy an off the shelf (and safe) solution like an off grid solar inverter?

Comment: How would the pure sine inverter synchronize to the grid? Or is this somehow a standalone setup you’re back feeding with a suicide cord? Also while not written and tangential: the company who makes the inverter you’ve pictured does not impress me with their products.

Comment: @jsotola I know only too well! Had to do it years ago and more than once ended up throwing the plug into the air as I forgot it was live and got bitten

Comment: How will the solar regulator maintain a voltage if any AC power is being drawn during shade?

Comment: Because this question comes around now and then: You can buy a solar panel with (enphase) **microinverter** and wire it up with a standard mains plug and it will work and be safe. Your electrical code may prohibit this use case though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many solar systems do not have a battery. This reduces cost and things that can fail. They use a grid tied inverter which locks onto the grid.

Comment: better for daytime running business.